# Is the user id automatically attached to a post, when posted on firebase?

Tags: firebase

When logged in and posting something, is the user uid automatically attached to that post?

At least if not changed somehow I mean.

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're talking about without seeing the code you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not, you have to set a field containing the uid yourself when creating a record to Firestore or Real Time Database. For example:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("/posts").add({content: "lalala", author: user.uid})
```